# SpriteKit - scene "exploding" under certain conditions

Tags: sprite-kit

I got a weird one.  I'm making a game that involves stacking.  Player touches the screen to drop objects and they need to stack up.  My scene has a container view that is 10x bigger than the screen in both dimensions.

A woodpecker periodically drifts in from the left and bumps into the stack, threatening to topple it.  I make the woodpecker stick to the stack by adding a fixed joint to one of the objects in the stack, the first one it makes contact with.

Here's what's happening: the play goes along fine for a while.  As the player stacks up objects, I scroll the container down so that it appears to be panning up, to follow the top of the stack.  When the stack gets to about 1500 points offset, weird things start happening.  When the woodpecker bumps into the left side of the stack, suddenly the whole thing explodes!  The items in the stack and woodpeckers seem to have been hit by a baseball bat.  They suddenly fly away at some incredible speed.  There is nothing in my code that would make it do that that I know of, and nothing particular about the offset of 1500.

I've NSLogged the X and Y positions and rotations of the woodpeckers and stack items.  After one of these 'explosions', I see several sprites at very high number positions (abs value), like hundreds of thousands, and they're spinning wildly (as if they had been hit with an explosions!)

This can go on for a few explosions, then, eventually the X and Y positions of 1 to 3 sprites becomes "nan".  This is correlated with a drastically reduced frame rate, like down to 0.1.

There's way too much code to include, and this problem is so weird I have no idea which snippets are most relevant.  If someone has an idea of how to approach debugging this, would greatly appreciate it.  Or let me know which bits of code you'd like to see if needed.

I've tried removing the fixed joint.  When there are no fixed joints, the problem doesn't happen.  It's also worth noting, that the woodpeckers do not respond to gravity but the stack items do.  I've tried changing this too, but same problem.

Comment: the joint creation code would be helpful. I'm not at all surprised by this problem, if you add a restriction to a body and in oarticular when that body overlaps with or collides with others, strong forces can accumulate. You could try and make the joint less 'strong', if that is possible.

Comment: It sounds like you are creating a considerable amount of potential energy that's converted to kinetic energy when the joint breaks. You can avoid this by making the woodpecker a child of the block it makes contact with instead of connecting the them with a physics joint.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Regarding strength of joints, surprisingly there is no such property in SKPhysicsJointFixed or its superclass.  The odd thing is that sometimes joints break, but there is no obvious way to set its strength.  Maybe SK is too new.

I tried making the bird a child of block.  It became tiny then didn't want to deal with the frame calculations so I just changed my plans. I'm going to make it bump and fly away instead of stick there.  Just side-stepping the problem.

Again, SK it too new; this is probably a bug, but hard to report since I haven't isolated it enough.